# Eco JavaScript templates in Rails without duplicate code?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, eco

I am using 'eco' gem with my Rails application to load [Eco templates](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco). The templates are really handy and automatically loaded by Rails 3.1 asset pipeline. The only problem is that each .js file generated by eco includes **the same** javascript code that mainly deals with html escaping. The code is about 1.5K in non-minified form. It may become significant overhead if application uses a lot of templates (like a hundred of them). Is there a way to take this code out of the js files and include only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See gist https://gist.github.com/2043682 , I have extracted out the common part.

Comment: The capture feature requires closure, otherwise it can be much simpler.